# When must I re-lock the Camera?

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

android.hardware.Camera tells me, of `lock()` and `unlock()`, that I "probably do not need this method" if I "am not recording video."  Well, I am recording video.

`unlock()` is supposed to be called "before calling android.media.MediaRecorder.setCamera(Camera)."  That's simple enough; I can just put the `unlock()` call immediately before the `setCamera()` call.  But what is the right time to call `lock()`?  Immediately after `setCamera()`?  After `MediaRecorder.stop()`?  Or at some other time?  How do I know when it's time to lock the Camera?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reconnection instead of lock after MediaRecorder.stop().

Comment: So are you saying that the time to call `lock()` (or `reconnect()`) is immediately following `MediaRecorder.stop()`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need call lock(), when you open a camera, Camera objects are locked by default unless unlock() is called. So basically lock() method is called when you want to prevent that no one can use camera service until you release the camera.